# Creating an htaccess for .py files

Tags: .htaccess

How might I create an .htaccess so that it replaces any www.w.com/cgi-bin/x.py with www.w.com/x/

So basically, it replaces /cgi-bin/$x.py with /$x and adds a trailing slash to make it /$x/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+cgi-bin/([^.]+)\.py [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ /cgi-bin/$1.py [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it cause an error when I try this. I currently have something that works but it won't put the trailing slash and it's not case sensitive: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/$1.py

Comment: see updated response, let me in detail what error it is causing.

Comment: Same error: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: see updated and check your Apache error.log for the actual reason of 500 error.

Comment: 166.78.181.113 - - [17/Mar/2014:02:54:27 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 63 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.71 Safari/534.24"

Comment: That's all I have when I check. All I know is that it's erroring.

Comment: Now it no longer errors but it does as it did before. It's not case insensitive and doesn't add a trailing slash but it will direct /cgi-bin/x.py to /x

Comment: That is probably due to `/cgi-bin/` being a special directory in Apache config which disables rewrite when path starts with `/cgi-bin/`

Comment: Why are you manipulating `/cgi-bin/` URLs? Can you not use any other directory path?

Comment: I've actually noticed that if I go to the /cgi-bin/x.py it works well. It redirects me to /x/ and x can be lower or upper case. What I want though is if I go to /x (which is really /cgi-bin/x.py), it will redirect me to /x/ and /x can be upper or lower case. So for example, /cgi-bin/test.py, I can also access by going to /Test and that will also change the url to /test/

Comment: Other than lower case all other requirements are met by above code. But presence of `/cgi-bin/` might be causing problem.